# Trapping the error message inside jquery ajax - from asp.net mvc action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I was able to get the actual error message before when I was using jquery ajax+ asp.net web services. However, the same code inside jquery $ajax error no longer works.

Inside my .js I have

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/DoSomething",
        data: JSON.stringify({ varname: varvalue }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (wo) { 
           alert('yay!');
        },


        error: function (xhr) {

            alert('error');

            if (xhr.responseText) {

                var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (err) {
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Unknown server error, please try again!");
                }
            } 

        }

    });
```

Inside my Controller I have

```
   public JsonResult DoSomething(string folderno)
   {
       CustomObject obj;

       //get the obj value from repository here
       throw new Exception("my test error message");
       return Json(obj);
   }
```

I looked at the Firebug and it appears that I am getting 
**"JSON.parse: unexpected character" error.**

What I am trying to do here is to fake a situation when getting obj from repository throws an exception. Obviously, `return Json(obj)` never gets reached.

My question is, how do I deal with this situation and trap the error messages on the JS side? Do I need to do something in my controller?

In my earlier set up of Jquery+asp.net web services, I could throw an exception inside my web service method (as shown in my action now) and it would be trapped in my ajax error and the error message would be parsed out.

Now, it would appear that I need to catch the exception and pack in myself....question is how? And do I need to do this inside every action? This seems like a lot of work.

Comment: see this question here for what I ended up doing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249479/getting-properties-from-jsonresult-on-the-js-side-inside-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

One thing I do is create a generic return object for AJAX calls.
Something like:

```
public class AJAXReturn
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your return functions wrap them in Exceptions (or create a generic exception handler) that will look something like:

```
public JsonResult DoSomething(string folderno)
{
   CustomObject obj = new { FolderNo = folderno };
   AJAXReturn result;

   try
   {
       result.Message = "OK";
       result.Result = obj;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       result.Message = "ERROR";
       result.Result = ex;
   }
   finally
   {
       return Json(result);
   }
}
```

Edit: On the javascript side, just check your result for `data.Message == 'OK'`.  If it isn't ok you can display either the specific exception info or anything you want.

Edit 2: Sorry I should've mentioned this will always return in the `success` callback so make sure you parse it there.