# Getting properties from JsonResult on the JS side inside jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am returning the following object JsonResult

```
return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = message },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
```

How do I get the error message out of it on the jquery side?

this is my error delegate of jquery ajax

```
error: function (result) {
        alert('error');
        alert(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

But it alerts as undefined. I tried `result.Data` as well as result.message....all `undefined`.

```
namespace myApp.ActionFilters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class AjaxException : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return;

            filterContext.Result = AjaxError(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext);

            //Let the system know that the exception has been handled
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        protected JsonResult AjaxError(string message, ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            //If message is null or empty, then fill with generic message
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                message = "Something went wrong while processing your request. Please refresh the page and try again.";

            //Set the response status code to 500
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            //Needed for IIS7.0
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = message },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In my Controller I have an Action to test this

```
 [AjaxException]
    public ActionResult TestErrorHandling(string id)
    {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            throw new Exception("oh no");
        }
        return Json(new { success = true });
     }
```

In my js

```
 id = "";
 $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/TestErrorHandling",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (result) {
        alert('some error occurred: ' + result.ErrorMessage);


        alert('success!');
    },

    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('error');
        alert(xhr.ErrorMessage);
    }

    });
```

Question: how do I get the errorMessage inside error delegate?

Comment: The first part of your code seems to be syntactically invalid. The parameters of a constructor function should always be enclosed by single parenthesis, not curly braces. Also, after the new keyword must always come a function, never an object. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Betamos, you probably should read about object and collection initializers syntax in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Oh, haha. Sorry 'bout that. Thought it was all JS. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Betamos, oh no, it's not your fault at all. It's the OP's fault to properly tag his question and put it into context. He didn't even mention that he is using asp.net-mvc initially which might completely explain people's confusion. He tagged it with javascript and jquery and obviously the code he showed doesn't make any sense for javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get the error message out of it on the jquery side?

Since you are returning a JSON object that comes with 200 status code the error callback will never be executed. So you could use the `success` callback in this case:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.ErrorMessage) {
        alert('some error occurred: ' + result.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Or if you want the error handler to be executed make sure that you set the proper status code in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return Json(new { ErrorMessage = message });
}
```

and then:

```
error: function (jqXHR) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
    alert('some error occurred: ' + result.ErrorMessage);
}
```

You might also find the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8231342/29407) useful.

Comment: actually, the error callback does get executed. .....it alerts 'error' then 'undefined'

Comment: I am even more confused than before:) lol. this jquery error seems the most mysterious part of jquery web dev. There is no clear documentation anywhere online on how to properly handle error handling and trap custom error messages on the JS side.

Comment: @sarsnake, what confuses you? Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ The error handler is invoked when the server returns an HTTP status code different than 200. In your code you return a JsonResult with a status code 200 => it's normal that the error callback won't be invoked. For jQuery if the server returns 200 status code it's a success and it makes sense.

Comment: @sarsnake, ah then probably there's an exception or something being thrown or the AJAX call doesn't get triggered at all due to a javascript error. Use a debugging tool like FireBug for example to understand what;s going on under the covers. There's not much more I could do to help here.

Comment: I am returning the above JsonResult as part of Exception handling. I will post full code

Comment: @sarsnake, now that you have posted your full code it is much more clear what you are doing and actually completely changes your question. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow please try to be as explicit as this. Now try what I suggested in my answer in the `error` callback: `var result = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText); alert('some error occurred: ' + result.ErrorMessage);`. What gives?

Comment: that worked! thank you very much. I guess an alternative way would be to make it execute inside success delegate and the then there would be no need for $.parseJson.

Comment: @sarsnake, yes, you could use the success handler but you should not set the status code to 500 in your action filter which IMHO is bad practice. I wouldn't recommend it. In case of an exception it's better to set status code to 500 and use the error handler.